# covert a result array in a cvs file

Tags: php, csv

How can i convert a result array into a CSV file.

Suppose i search for something and i get the result like so --

```
Array
    (
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [category] => phone cases
        [sale_price] => 90,99
        [price] => 120
        [product_name] => "iphone 6 plus" case transparent
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 13
        [category] => shoes
        [sale_price] => 180,99
        [price] => 200
        [product_name] => blue platform shoes
        )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 14
        [category] => wallet
        [sale_price] => 150
        [price] => 250
        [product_name] => velvet wallet
```

i have tried like so ---

```
$csvFile = fopen('/path/to/csvFile.csv', 'w+');
fputcsv($csvFile, $array);
```

but always get the error --

> Notice: Array to string conversion (500 Internal Server Error)

Now how can i convert this result into a CSV file !
Any one knows any simple solution for this problem !

Comment: `fputcsv()` is all you need.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I googled `php array to csv` and plenty results came up. Are you having trouble with something in specific?

Comment: @FirstOne have actually tried the fputcsv() but i am getting some error ! and thanks for tips, i voted up ur tips !

Comment: Ok, you should edit your question and post what you've tried and what's not working with it. Post the error too and if you are not getting the expected result, post what it is then.

Comment: @FirstOne i have edit the question now, can u kindly have a look please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the file using [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Iterate over the array and pass each line to [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

```
$csvFile = fopen('/path/to/csvFile.csv', 'w+');
foreach($yourArray as $line){
    fputcsv($csvFile, $line);
}
```

Comment: but when i tried that i always get the same error **"Notice: Array to string conversion (500 Internal Server Error)"**

Comment: Sorry, I see fputcsv is for a single line, not entire contents of array. Code snippet above edited, try that?

Comment: thanks a lot for your awesome answer, thanks dude :)